# PowerQuery COUNTIF Previous Dates

Tags: excel, aggregate, powerquery, excel-2016, m

I'm a little rusty on PowerQuery.
I need to count "previous" entries in the same table.

For example, let's say we have a table of car sales.
For the purposes of PowerQuery, this table will be named `tblCarSales`

[image]

**I need to add two aggregate columns.**

The first aggregate column is the count of previous sales.
The Excel formula would be `=COUNTIF([Sale Date],"<"&[@[Sale Date]])`

[image]

The second aggregate column is the count of previous sales ***by make***.
The Excel formula would be `=COUNTIFS([Sale Date],"<"&[@[Sale Date]],[Make],[@Make])`

[image]

How can this behavior be accomplished in PowerQuery, instead of using Excel formulas?
For example, I'm starting with the source statement:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblCarSales"]}[Content]
in
    Source
```

... where the source table only provides the `Make`, `Model`, and `Sale Date` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing using List and Table functions. I'll show both.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblCarSales"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Previous Sale Count",
                         (C) => List.Count(List.Select(Source[Sale Date],
                                each _ < C[Sale Date]))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Previous Sale Count By Make",
                         (C) => Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Source,
                                (S) => S[Sale Date] < C[Sale Date] and S[Make] = C[Make])))
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

We have to use the functions so that Power Query knows what context we're looking at the columns in. For further reading, check out this [Power Query M Primer](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/12/08/4270/power-query-m-primer-part3-functions-function-values-passing-returning-defining-inline-recursion).

Comment: Worked like a charm! It's all coming back to me now - I vaguely remember working with list and table functions a year ago. This gives me a great jumping-off point, for re-learning a semi-forgotten language/skill. Thanks for the refresher!