# How can I aggregate # previous values (moving average) values for depending on column in PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I want to calculate the moving average of days projects spend in a given stage in PowerQuery / a Pivottable, grouped by week of completion.

**Input**

For example, let's take these data points. These are projects that end in a specific year and week.

[image]

**To make it simple, let's focus on one stage first.**

[image]

**Output**

The output would look similar to this:

[image]

**Function**

This is where the problem lies.

*== Approach 1.0*
I imagine it goes something like this:

- Index all the projects. (As done with project_index).
- For every week, find the project with the max index.
- Somehow, average the opportunities from max-index to max-index - 2.

*== Approach 1.1*

Another possible approach, that I am unsure about how to execute as well:

- For every project, take the index + 2 and find out the week of project_index + 2. (Kind of like a vlookup.) This is how I would attempt to solve it in a VBA.

`vlookup(index + 2, matrix (project-index, year, week), and then get both the columns year and week)`

*=== Approach 2: Fancy functions that confuse me*

Another fellow had a problem that almost sounds the same. I am almost sure the table and list functions will solve this,
[PowerQuery COUNTIF Previous Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304608/powerquery-countif-previous-dates)

I have attempted something like this, but I have yet to understand how these functions really work. And the scope of column vs row is quite strange.

```
//Alternatively to Source, might first need to GroupBy Week or Project.
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Moving Average last 3 Projects",
                         (C) => List.Sum(List.Select([project_index] - 2,
                                each _ < C[project_index]), [Days_in_Stage])),
```

*=== Approach 3: Measure*

Another fellow has a simpler problem, where he doesn't need to aggregate multiple values and stages by week, but rather 1D-data. I feel like with the right GroupBy or possibly pivoting the [Stage] as columns, this solution could have some merit.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Need-help-SUM-or-AVERAGE-last-7-Previous-Records-Not-Using-Date/td-p/505276

**Long story short: Does anyone know how best to approach this?**

Comment: This is possible to do in the query editor but seems better suited to do in a measure. Is there a reason it has to be done there?

Comment: @AlexisOlson If it works better in a measure, measure it is!